# The only player who can use [my / his / their] hands

Tags: pronouns

If a person is talking about his experience being a goalie in soccer, should which pronoun should he use? "His" seems grammatically correct but sounds really weird.

Comment: Why does it sound "really weird"?

Comment: If the person speaking is a "he", then I suppose he would say "his", if a "she" then "her". What's "weird" about that?

Comment: The only one that would sound weird is _my_, or _his_ if the speaker is not a man. _Their_ is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

" His " is  a possessive pronoun.  It means something is owned by a man or a boy. So the use of 'his'in the sentence is correct, if the player you are talking about is a man or a boy.